# How can I display javac error messages with passthru in PHP?

Tags: java, php, stdout, javac, stderr

As I understand it, PHP's passthru displays the unadulterated output of the console - including all outputs, like STDERR. I'm trying to javac a file from a PHP file like so:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    if(file_put_contents("code.java", "aaaaaa"))
    {
        passthru("javac -verbose code.java");
        echo("Done.");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("UNEXPECTED PHP ERROR");
    }
?>
```

As you can probably guess, "aaaaaaa" should NOT compile - and this I expect output from the javac call (not to mention the -verbose). However, when I access the web page, I notice two things:

1. code.java is created successfully and filled with the data I specify.
2. The only output to the webpage is "Done."

Note that if I call the exact same command from the cmd prompt, I get a whole slew of output. What's going on here?

tl;dr; why am I not getting any output from passthru()?

EDIT: If I change the passthru command string to "echo PLEASEWORK" it displays outputs correctly

---

For some reason I can't comment -
Quamis, what IS the prefered method of executing this cmd and capturing all output?

Comment: Output to `STDERR` goes to Apache's error logs. You'll need to redirect it to `STDOUT` to see it in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the man file http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php i can read clearly "This function should be used in place of exec() or system() **when the output from the Unix command is binary** data which needs to be passed directly back to the browser". This means passthry is not your best friend for this task:)

This is not your case...

try using `passthru("your_command_here 2>&1")` to capture both stdout and stderr.

Comment: Billybob for some reason cannot comment, and he is asking you: "what IS the prefered method of executing this cmd and capturing all output?"

Comment: `exec("your_command_here 2>&1")` should do the trick in a "preferred" way

Comment: That was Billybob's question ;-) I just wanted to pass his words before I flagged hist post as not-an-answer.

Comment: @Arsen7, sorry, now I've seen your comments:) its weird that he even has the same avatar though..

Comment: thanks Quamis & arsen7, I will try that as soon as I get a chance!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, output to `STDERR` goes to Apache's log files. To "see" it in the browser, you'll need to redirect it to `STDOUT`:

```
$command = "javac -verbose code.java 2>&1";
$result = passthru($command);
```

This is called [file descriptor redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).